# how to show a legend on dual y-axis ggplot

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, data.table, gtable

I am trying to compose a dual y-axis chart using ggplot. Firstly let me say that I am not looking for a discussion on the merits of whether or not it is good practice to do so. I find them to be particularly useful when looking at time based data to identify trends in 2 discrete variables. A further discussion of this is better suited to crossvalidated in my opinion.

[Kohske](https://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2) provides a very good example of how to do it, which I have used to great effect so far. I am however at my limits to include a legend for both y-axes. I have also seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/how-to-use-ggplot2-make-plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701606/how-to-plot-bars-and-one-line-on-two-y-axes-in-the-same-chart-with-r-ggplot/22734987#comment42005315_22734987) but none seem to address the issue of including a legend.

I've got a reproduceable example using the diamonds dataset from ggplot.

**Data**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(data.table)
library(scales)

grid.newpage()

dt.diamonds <- as.data.table(diamonds)

d1 <- dt.diamonds[,list(revenue = sum(price),
                        stones = length(price)),
                  by=clarity]

setkey(d1, clarity)
```

**Charts**

```
p1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x=clarity,y=revenue, fill="#4B92DB")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x="clarity", y="revenue") +
  scale_fill_identity(name="", guide="legend", labels=c("Revenue")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar, expand=c(0,0)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="#4B92DB"), 
        legend.position="bottom")

p2 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x=clarity, y=stones, colour="red")) +
  geom_point(size=6) + 
  labs(x="", y="number of stones") + expand_limits(y=0) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=comma, expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = '',values =c("red","green"), labels = c("Number of Stones"))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "red")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA,colour="grey50"),
        legend.position="bottom")

# extract gtable
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))


pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t,
                     pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)
# axis tweaks
ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")
ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
ax <- ga$children[[2]]
ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
ax$grobs[[1]]$x <- ax$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.15, "cm")
g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)
# draw it
grid.draw(g)
```

**QUESTION:** Does anyone have some tips on how to get the 2nd part of the legend to show?

The following are the charts produced in order p1, p2, combined p1&p2, you'll notice that the legend for p2 doesn't show in the combined chart.

**p1**

[image: p1]

**p2**

[image: p2]

**combined p1 & p2**

[image: combined p1 & p2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to the technique you use above you can extract the legends, bind them and then overwrite the plot legend with them.

So starting from `# draw it` in your code

```
# extract legend
leg1 <- g1$grobs[[which(g1$layout$name == "guide-box")]]
leg2 <- g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "guide-box")]]

g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")]] <- 
                                  gtable:::cbind_gtable(leg1, leg2, "first")
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: That works an absolute treat. If I was wanting to extend it for inclusion in a function like my question [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728852/create-function-to-ggplot-with-data-table) how do I force the legend with my colour set outside of `aes`? or alternately be able to pass a single colour or data.table column to `aes_string` to set the fill?

Comment: I've found a hack solution for now. As the `aes_string` seems to take strings and convert them to variable names, I have escaped my red to `"\"red\""` and it seems to work well.

Comment: You seem to be quite familiar with grob, I am wondering how this might be extended to allow for facets too? Should I ask this as a new question?