# Secondary / Dual axis - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am opening this question for three reasons : First, to re-open the dual-axis discussion with ggplot. Second, to ask if there is a non-torturing generic approach to do that. And finally to ask for your help with respect to a work-around.

I realize that there are multiple discussions and questions on how to add a secondary axis to a ggplot. Those usually end up in one of two conclusions:

1. **It's bad, don't do it**: Hadley Wickham answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right), concluding that it is not possible. He had a very good argument that *"using separate y scales (not y-scales that are transformations of each other) are fundamentally flawed"*.
2. **If you insist, over-complicate your life and use grids** : for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727741/how-to-show-a-legend-on-dual-y-axis-ggplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701606/how-to-plot-bars-and-one-line-on-two-y-axes-in-the-same-chart-with-r-ggplot/22734987)

However, here are some situations that I often face, in which the visualization would greatly benefit from dual-axis. I abstracted the concepts below.

1. The plot is wide, hence **duplicating** the y-axis on the right side would help (or x-axis on the top) would ease interpretation. *(We've all stumbled across one of those plots where we need to use a ruler on the screen, because the axis is too far)*
   [image]
2. I need to add a new axis that is a **transformation** to the original axes (eg: percentages, quantiles, .. ). *(I am currently facing a problem with that. Reproducible example below)*
   [image]
3. And finally, adding **Grouping/Meta information**: I stumble across that when using categorical data with multiple-level, *(e.g.: Categories = {1,2,x,y,z}, which are "meta-divided" into letters and numerics.)*   Even though color-coding the meta-levels and adding a legend or even facetting solve the issue, things get a little bit simpler with a secondary axis, where the user won't need to match the color of the bars to that of the legend.
   [image]

**General question:** Given the new extensibility features [ggplot 2.0.0](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/), is there a more-robust no-torture way to have dual-axis without using grids?

And one final comment: I absolutely agree that the wrong use of dual-axis can be dangerously misleading... But, isn't that the case for information visualization and data science in general?

---

**Work-around question**:

Currently, I need to have a percentage-axis (2nd case). I used `annotate` and `geom_hline` as a workaround. However, I can't move the text outside the main plot. `hjust` also didn't seem to work with me.

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Random values generation - with some manipulation : 
maxVal = 500
value = sample(1:maxVal, size = 100, replace = T)
value[value < 400] = value[value < 400] * 0.2
value[value > 400] = value[value > 400] * 0.9


# Data Frame prepartion : 
labels = paste0(sample(letters[1:3], replace = T, size = length(value)), as.character(1:length(value)))
df = data.frame(sample = factor(labels, levels = labels), value = sort(value, decreasing = T))


# Plotting : Adding Percentages/Quantiles as lines  
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = sample, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "grey90", aes(y = maxVal )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",  fill = "#00bbd4") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0, maxVal)) + # Min and max values
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(maxVal*0.25, maxVal*0.5, maxVal*0.75), alpha = 0.2) +  # Marking the 25%, 50% and 75% values 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = rep(100,3), y = c(maxVal*0.25, maxVal*0.5, maxVal*0.75), 
           label = c("25%", "50%", "75%"), vjust = 0, hjust = 0.2) +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(rep(2,4), units = "lines"))
```

Comment: you could use latticeExtra if you really want to have a second y axis

Comment: @MLavoie , it's a bit frustrating that one would change from ggplot to lattice, for such a straight-forward reason..

Comment: I remember that Hadley wrote somewhere that secondary axes which are transformations of the primary axes would be acceptable and he would probably accept a pull request that adds such functionality.

Answer (score 4):

In response to *#1*

> *We've all stumbled across one of those plots where we need to use a ruler on the screen, because the axis is too far*

[cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html).

```
# Assign your original plot to some variable, `gpv` <- ggplot( ... )
ggdraw(switch_axis_position(gpv, axis="y", keep="y"))
```